# Using a Rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use Peter Marklund's [html test plugin](http://marklunds.com/articles/one/328) to automatically validate all of my HTML pages. I'm following his [README instructions](http://github.com/peter/html_test/tree/255803d268bda97a4861de6fcf48440c769722f0/README) and have installed the plugin successfully. However, when I use his "assert_validates" method in a test, I get the following error message:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Html::Test::Validator::RailsTidy
```

To me this looks like the plugin isn't being loaded (and thus the classes/methods aren't avilable). Is there something that I need to do (such as a "require", etc) in order to load/activate a plugin? I haven't done anything besides what I've described above. I get the feeling that there's something general I'm missing rather than something broken in the plugin itself. (If that's not the case, then I'll go to Peter for additional help.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to also have the [RailsTidy](http://blog.cosinux.org/pages/rails-tidy) plugin, it's not clear from Peter's remarks if he pulled out the code that was needed or if you need both.

Comment: Yup, installing RailsTidy did it; thanks a bunch. I'm going to ping Peter to update his README